# SQL Server : SELECT join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, subquery

Table structure:

```
#IN
(
    REFNUM NVARCHAR(5),
    QUANTITY INT,
    BIRTH DATE,
    WH NVARCHAR(10),
    BIN NVARCHAR(10),
    WEEK INT,
    DAY INT
)

#OUT 
(
    REFNUM NVARCHAR(5),
    QUANTITY INT,
    BIRTH DATE,
    WH NVARCHAR(10),
    BIN NVARCHAR(10),
    WEEK INT,
    DAY INT
)

#TRANSFER 
(
    REFNUM NVARCHAR(5),
    QUANTITY INT,
    BIRTH DATE,
    WH NVARCHAR(10),
    BIN NVARCHAR(10),
    OUTWH NVARCHAR(10),
    INBIN NVARCHAR(10),
    WEEK INT,
    DAY INT 
)



(Insert test data)
Insert into #IN (REFNUM, QUANTITY, BIRTH, WH, BIN) VALUES ('0001', 100, '2019.01.29', 'A01', 'A01')
Insert into #IN (REFNUM, QUANTITY, BIRTH, WH, BIN) VALUES ('0002', 100, '2019.01.29', 'A01', 'A02')
Insert into #IN (REFNUM, QUANTITY, BIRTH, WH, BIN) VALUES ('0003', 100, '2019.01.29', 'A01', 'A03')
Insert into #IN (REFNUM, QUANTITY, BIRTH, WH, BIN) VALUES ('0004', 100, '2019.01.29', 'A01', 'A04')

Insert into #OUT (REFNUM, QUANTITY, BIRTH, WH, BIN) VALUES ('0001', 10, '2019.01.29', 'A01', 'A01')
Insert into #OUT (REFNUM, QUANTITY, BIRTH, WH, BIN) VALUES ('0001', 10, '2019.01.29', 'A01', 'A01')
Insert into #OUT (REFNUM, QUANTITY, BIRTH, WH, BIN) VALUES ('0002', 10, '2019.01.29', 'A01', 'A02')
Insert into #OUT (REFNUM, QUANTITY, BIRTH, WH, BIN) VALUES ('0002', 10, '2019.01.29', 'A01', 'A02')

Insert into #TRANSFER (REFNUM, QUANTITY, BIRTH, WH, BIN, INWH, INBIN) VALUES ('0001', 10, '2019.01.29', 'A01', 'A01', 'A01', 'A03')
Insert into #TRANSFER (REFNUM, QUANTITY, BIRTH, WH, BIN, INWH, INBIN) VALUES ('0001', 10, '2019.01.29', 'A01', 'A01', 'A01', 'A03')
Insert into #TRANSFER (REFNUM, QUANTITY, BIRTH, WH, BIN, INWH, INBIN) VALUES ('0001', 10, '2019.01.29', 'A01', 'A02', 'A01', 'A04')
Insert into #TRANSFER (REFNUM, QUANTITY, BIRTH, WH, BIN, INWH, INBIN) VALUES ('0001', 10, '2019.01.29', 'A01', 'A02', 'A01', 'A04')
```

---

the result I'd like to get :

```
REFNUM QUANTITY WH  BIN
0001   80       A01 A01
0001   120      A01 A03
0002   80       A01 A02
0002   120      A01 A04
```

and the query I got so far :

```
SELECT 
I.REFNUM,
I.WH,
I.BIN,
O.WH,
O.BIN,
T.WH,
T.BIN,
T.REFNUM,
(SELECT QUANTITY FROM #IN I) - ISNULL((SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM #OUT O),0) -   ISNULL((SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM #TRANSFER T), 0) AS RESULT 
FROM #IN I 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN #OUT O 
ON I.REFNUM = O.REFNUM 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN #TRANSFER T
ON O.REFNUM = T.REFNUM 
GROUP BY I.REFNUM, O.REFNUM, T.REFNUM, I.WH, I.BIN, O.WH, O.BIN, T.WH, 
T.BIN
ORDER BY I.REFNUM
```

and I get an error saying : 
"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

How should my query be to get the result I want by joining those 3 tables? 
(I am trying to create a procedure to get the result. So if it's easier to create temporary tables I could do that too)

Comment: ***WHAT*** is that error?? Remember: we cannot see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind (just yet) - you'll have to **tell us** and show the error that happens!

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Show what queries for parts of this you can do correctly, including the largest part of this code that acts correctly. Also your descriptions of what you want (including re sums) is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to examples (including correct smaller queries) to say what you mean.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.

Comment: The error msg i got was "Column '#IN.QUANTITY' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: • That error message is faq. And read how to use group by. Before considering posting please always google many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal and/or error message, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. • Where is your query? Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. • Clarify via edits, not comments. • Google 'stackexchange notifications' to learn to use @x to notify one non-poster non-sole commenter x about a comment.

Comment: How is the new error message not clear? A subquery has >1 row. Anyway it is *also* a faq. Read re scalar subqueries. Show a working part of this code. PS Please do not edit a question post in a way that invalidates reasonable answer posts. Fix the old post to ask its question & post a new question. Please ask one question per post. Don't mix a question about your error message with a question about your overall goal. PS Learn what left/right join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left/right table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of an outer join.

Comment: i solved it anyway sorry for confusion then

Answer (score 0):

As your #out & #transfer tables have duplicate values... you may try something like this

```
WITH CTE_OUT
AS (
    SELECT REFNUM
        ,SUM(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY --.... OTHERCOLUMNS 
    FROM #OUT
    GROUP BY REFNUM
    )
    ,CTE_TRANSFER
AS (
    SELECT REFNUM
        ,SUM(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY --.... OTHERCOLUMNS 
    FROM #TRANSFER
    GROUP BY REFNUM
    )
SELECT O.REFNUM
    ,ISNULL(I.QUANTITY, 0) - ISNULL(O.QUANTITY, 0) - ISNULL(T.QUANTITY, 0) AS QUANTITY -- WHAT EVER IS YOUR EXPRESSION 
FROM #IN I
LEFT JOIN CTE_OUT O ON I.REFNUM = O.REFNUM
LEFT JOIN CTE_TRANSFER T ON O.REFNUM = T.REFNUM
GROUP BY O.REFNUM -- OTHER COLUMNS
```

Comment: I get an error saying "Column '#OUT.WEEK' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."